# Parse time format "DD/MM/YYYY at hh:mm:ss" & others using std::chrono::from_stream()

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono, visual-c++-2019

I'm currently trying to parse some info about the start time of an experiment as listed in a log file. After reading in the file important info, e.g column titles, start time, time between measurements, is parsed using `<regex>`.

I'm trying to use the `std::chrono::from_stream(...)` function to parse a string with the format "DD/MM/YYYY at hh:mm:ss" into a `std::chrono::time_point`, example of a string:

> 08/03/2021 at 09:37:25

At the moment I'm attempting this using the following function which attempts to construct a duration from a provided string to parse & a string to parse it with, then converting that to a time_point so I have control over the clock used:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using nano = std::chrono::duration<std::uint64_t, std::nano>;

template <typename Duration>
Duration TimeFormat(const std::string& str,
                    const std::string& fmt,
                    const Duration& default_val)
{
    Duration dur;
    std::stringstream ss{ str };
    std::chrono::from_stream(ss, fmt.c_str(), dur);

    /*
    from_stream sets the failbit of the input stream if it fails to parse
    any part of the input format string or if it receives any contradictory
    information.
    */
    if (ss.good())
    {
        std::cout << "Successful parse!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << dur.count() << std::endl;
        return dur;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed parse!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << dur.count() << std::endl;
        return default_val;
    }
}

int main()
{
    /*
    The file is already read in, and regex matches the correct line from the log file and a
    format pattern from a related config file.
    */
    
    /*
    Two different lines in the log file give:
    - str1 = test start time.
    - str2 = time between each measurement.
    */
    std::string str1("08/03/2021 at 09:37:25"), str2("00:00:05");
    std::string fmt1("%d/%m/%Y at %H:%M:%S"), fmt2("%H:%M:%S");

    auto test1 = TimeFormat<nano>(str1, fmt1, nano::zero());
    /*
    --> "Failed parse!" & test1.count() = 14757395258967641292
    A little research indicates that this is what VS initializes variables to
    in debug mode. If run in release mode test1.count() = 0 in my tests.
    */

    auto test2 = TimeFormat<nano>(str2, fmt2, nano::zero());
    /* 
    --> "Failed parse!" & test2.count() = 5000000000 (5 billion nanoseconds)
    Chose nanoseconds because it also has to handle windows file times which are measured
    relative to 01/01/1601 in hundreds of nanoseconds. Might be worth pointing out.
    What's weird is that it fails even though the value it reads is correct.
    */

    /*
    ... Convert to a time_point after this,
    e.g auto t1 = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, nano>(test1);
    */
}
```

The MS documentation for from_stream can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/chrono-functions?view=msvc-160#std-chrono-from-stream). With details about different format characters just after the from_stream docs.

Comment: It should be noted that this: `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, nano>(test1)` is meaningless. High-resolution clock has no well-defined epoch, so time-points in such a clock don't actually represent any particular date. It only makes sense to apply a date-derived duration for a clock that has a well-defined epoch (since that duration is the time since that epoch). If the time taken from the text is not UTC time, then you need to figure out *what* time it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ss.is_good()` ?

Is that a type-o in your question or an extension in the Visual Studio std::lib?

I'm going to guess it is a type-o and that you meant `ss.good()`...

The [`good()` member function](http://eel.is/c++draft/iostate.flags#lib:good,basic_ios) checks if all state flags are off:

- `failbit`
- `badbit`
- `eofbit`

`eofbit` in particular often does not mean "error".  It simply means that the parsing reached the end of the stream.  You are interpreting "end of stream" as a parsing error.

Instead check `failbit` or `badbit`.  This is most easily done with the [`fail()` member function](http://eel.is/c++draft/iostate.flags#lib:fail,basic_ios).

```
if (!ss.fail())
    ...
```

### Update

> Any idea why it still won't pass the first string though?

I'm not 100% positive if it is a bug in the VS implementation, or a bug in the C++ spec, or a bug in neither.  Either way, it wouldn't return what you're expecting.

For me (using the [C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)), the first parse is successful and returns

```
34645000000000
```

which if printed out in hh:mm:ss.fffffffff format is:

```
09:37:25.000000000
```

That is, only the time-part is contributing to the return value.  This is clearly not what you intended.  Your first test appears to intend to parse a `time_point`, not a `duration`.

Here is a slightly rewritten program that I think will do what you want, parsing a `time_point` in the first test, and a `duration` in the second:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using nano = std::chrono::duration<std::uint64_t, std::nano>;

template <typename TimeType>
TimeType TimeFormat(const std::string& str,
                    const std::string& fmt,
                    const TimeType& default_val)
{
    TimeType dur;
    std::stringstream ss{ str };
    std::chrono::from_stream(ss, fmt.c_str(), dur);

    /*
    from_stream sets the failbit of the input stream if it fails to parse
    any part of the input format string or if it receives any contradictory
    information.
    */
    if (!ss.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Successful parse!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << dur << std::endl;
        return dur;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed parse!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << dur << std::endl;
        return default_val;
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::string str1("08/03/2021 at 09:37:25"), str2("00:00:05");
    std::string fmt1("%d/%m/%Y at %H:%M:%S"), fmt2("%H:%M:%S");

    auto test1 = TimeFormat(str1, fmt1, std::chrono::sys_time<nano>{});
    auto test2 = TimeFormat(str2, fmt2, nano::zero());
}
```

For me this outputs:

```
Successful parse!
2021-03-08 09:37:25.000000000
Successful parse!
5000000000ns
```

If one wanted the output of the first test in terms of nanoseconds since epoch, then one could extract that from the `dur` `time_point` variable with `dur.time_since_epoch()`.  This would then output:

```
1615196245000000000ns
```

Comment: Or just `if (ss)`, which can also be `if (from_stream(...))`

Comment: True.  I kind of like the more verbose `!fail()`, but this is a stylistic choice.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. That was indeed a typo, thanks for pointing it out. Thanks for pointing out that good() checks the eofbit, I hadn't realised. Any idea why it still won't pass the first string though?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it's a little embarrassing how long I've been stuck on this problem.